# Azure ASP.NET Core .NET 6 Angular app failed to start

Tags: angular, azure, azure-web-app-service, .net-6.0

Publish Angular.NET6 app to Azure App Service

In Visual Studio 2022 I have made a new project "ASP.NET Core with Angular" on the .NET 6 Framework.

[image: Picture]

After which I pressed F5, and got this result…

[image: Picture]

Everything worked fine.

Then I created an Azure App Service on .NET 6…

[image: Picture]

After which I made a Publish for it.

But the page always failed. I have tried several times but always get either this error.

> HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start

Or this error.

> HTTP Error 500.31 - ANCM Failed to Find Native Dependencies

Now I have for a few days, tried to follow all the good advice online, but without success. So now I hope there is someone here who can help me further…

Comment: You are probably missing a configuration for your app. There is a console window on the App Service webpage, open up that console window and type in the name of "<nameOfYourProject>.exe" and press enter. This should try to run the project and gives you better error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to repro and able to access the application without any issues.
You can use 2 ways to deploy Angular Web App to Azure.

#### Option 1

**From Visual Studio**

- Created "ASP.NET Core with Angular" on the .NET 6
- While deploying from visual Studio, you can select the existing App Service if having

[image]

or you can create new app service from visual studio publish profile in Azure and deploy to that.

[image]

- In Azure Portal, check the configuration of the deployed App and it will be changed according to your deployed app configuration.

[image]

#### Option 2

**Using Azure App Service**

- In Azure Portal =>Create App Service
- Make the required changes in configuration section
- Click on QuickStart option in the left index menu to proceed further about how to create and deploy any application to this app service using various editors.
  [image]

[image]

> [HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/test/troubleshoot-azure-iis?view=aspnetcore-6.0#50030-in-process-startup-failure)

> [HTTP Error 500.31 - ANCM Failed to Find Native Dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/test/troubleshoot-azure-iis?view=aspnetcore-6.0#50031-ancm-failed-to-find-native-dependencies)

Comment: I do not know what the error has been, but now all the test pages I made work and I have not changed anything about them.

I think the Azure people have fixed a bug…

But thanks for the help 